# Using Laravel's routing feature and nothing else

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to know if it's possible to use the amazing routing function implemented in Laravel and nothing more from the framework. This is a small project and I don't want to use the whole thing.

Comment: You can, all illuminate packages are divided in subtree repositories. The routing can be found [here](https://github.com/illuminate/routing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to use [`Illuminate` components](https://github.com/illuminate) as standalone components in non-Laravel application. I'm sure [this project](https://github.com/mattstauffer/Torch) will be helpful. An example for the `Routing` component can be found [here](https://github.com/mattstauffer/Torch/tree/master/components/routing).